# To calculate maximum column width in Excel precisely

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Adobe as default and active printer. The printer is set as A4 paper, which has dimension of 2970*2100.

I like to set my worksheet from columns A:Q look like precisely the same as A4 paper.
That’s what I have done:
I calculated ceiling value of columns width of A:Q bounded by 2100mmm; and
My page setup is set as A4 paper size, Portrait, adjust to 100% and all margins set as 0.

According to this article, width is in point.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.width

I used the following vba code to get the column width in MMM of columns A:Q:

```
?1 / Application.CentimetersToPoints(1) * sheet1.Range("A1:Q1").width *100
```

It return 2094.32 which is less than the A4 dimension 2100.

However, in the window pagebreak view, the pagebreak show between column P and column Q.

I am expecting the pagebreak should be in column Q and column R.

Please kindly teach me what am I missing here and how can I fix my calculation on the ceiling value of column width from columns A:Q.

Comment: My guess is that there are margins that add to the total width (and height). 
Why don't you multiply by something less than 100 (99.5?) to make room for those margins?

Comment: Because I need to know what the margin is before I multiple the minimizing ratio. I am afraid that maybe 99.5 work this time. But need 99 to work for next time. If I use 99, but maybe the next next time is too narrow for A4 paper.

Comment: You can check the size of the margins within your code, and compensate for that (`sheet1.PageSetup.LeftMargin` and `RightMargin`)

Comment: It both returned as zero

Comment: Why do you believe that exactly 100% is required? Put the scale ratio at 95% and go with that!

Comment: Because I want to scale of the content can be as large as it possibly can.